# Is there a way to show IME on full screen mode of Unity3d Game

Tags: unity-game-engine, fullscreen, resolution

I am searching a method, how to show IME on full screen mode of unity3d game. Now I only get one method : add " -popupwindow" argument to my game.exe, and set the game resolution to may native desk resolution. Any other idea will be welcome, thanks advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For standalone builds you can use [Screen.fullScreen = true](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Screen-fullScreen.html).

Comment: thanks, but if I use Screen.fullScreen = true, the IME can't show on top of my game window